# SQL query big duration increase after cpu+mainboard upgrade

Tags: sql-server, hardware, duration

After upgrading server hardware (cpu+mainboard) I'm having a big increase in query duration for really small and simple querys.

Software: Windows Server 2012 R2 + SQL Server 2014
Storage: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 2TB Disk
Old Hardware: i7-4790k 4.0Ghz 4core cpu + Asus H97M-E mainboard + 32 GB DDR3
New Hardware: i9-7900X 3.60Ghz 10core cpu + Asus Prime X299 mainboard + 32 GB DDR4

Query Sample:
UPDATE CLIE_PRECIOS_COMPRA SET [c_res_tr] = '0.0' WHERE eje ='18' AND mes =8 AND dia =27 AND hor =19 AND unipro='001'

SQL Profiler Result :
Old Hardware - CPU: 0, Reads 4, Writes 0, Duration 123
Old Hardware - CPU: 0, Reads 4, Writes 0, Duration 2852

I've checked network speed of both server to be the same but anyway I'm running the querys directly in the server throught Microsoft SQL Server Management console to avoid applicactions or network issues.

Checked Storage speed too being the same both at reading and writting in old and new hardware.

Also played with paralelism and tried diferent scenarios even disabling paralelism with the same result.

Of course the data is the same having the same copy of SQL database in both hardware.

I've set the duration to be showed in microseconds instead of miliseconds to appreciate better the diference.

The diference in duration for a single query is not really visible to user but the problem is that there are several thousands querys of this type and the time increase is important.

Any hint or thing to investigate would be really appreciated.

Current Execution Plan New Server: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJYDtQQD7
Current Execution Plan Old Server: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SynyW4mPQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to look at the execution plan. Then you can upload it here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ Remember to provide us a link.

Comment: Is it possible your statistics are stale?  You could update and see if that's the culprit.

Comment: And maybe rebuild your indexes on the new server (which will also update statistics) and see if that helps any.

Comment: @Sean-lange, updated post with execution plan but think not related to specific query because of happening with several of them working with diferent tables on the same database.

Comment: Can you get the actual execution plan. The information contained is VERY different than the estimated plan.

Comment: @SeanLange, sorry updated with actual execution plan.

Comment: I would also update statistics, check index fragmentation and see if it needs to be reord/rebuild. Maybe you could show us the execution plan on the old server?

Comment: @Greenspark, updated statistics with no sense

Comment: @pmbAustin indexes rebuilt with no changes

Comment: What about storage? Is it the exact same storage? Or did you move the database to another disc or array?

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey, updated statitics, checked index fragmentation and rebuilt index. Updated main post with Old server execution plan.

Comment: Could it be spectre fix or some other firmware things?

Comment: Have you checked the CPU assignment?

Comment: @SeanLange, moved SSD disk from old to new server so exact same storage but looks like ssd benchmark test throw different result when executed with the same ssd unit in new and old server as showed in this captured: https://imgur.com/a/av1mD4x

Comment: @Hitobat no spectre things over there, trying to play now at bios level with cpu configuration

Comment: Now dealing with Intel SpeedStep, SpeedShift and CPU States. Looks like any involved... I’ll keep you informed.

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED!!!  It was SATA Drivers. Using standard Microsoft SATA/AHCI did the trick. Using propietary drivers from Intel C200+/C600+ SATA Controller was making any type of delay accesing SQL Server Databases. Tried diferent versions of Intel propietary drivers for my board with same result. Please ask more info if needed. Now only changing the SATA Drivers duration went from around 3000 microseconds to low than 200.